# How to highlight the multiple occurence of string in edit plus

Tags: edit

I want to highlight all occurrence of the particular word or string in my edit plus text area while i click on that particular string or by using find operation ...

Answer (score 2):

Open 'Views' menu and select 'Word Highlighting'.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu section:

Select view > Select the Word Highlighting Option.

[image: Please check attachment for more information.]

Thanks!!
Harshad